# Django runserver performance problem on localhost

Tags: django, performance, development-environment

I have a strange problem in Django development environment.

I have changed my ISP and my setup is as follows:

ISP -> Modem -> WirelessRouter -> Desktop (connected wirelessly)

When I start my development enviornment and access the env http://localhost:8000, the performance is horrible, each request takes couple of around 10 seconds.

The last time I used the dev environment things were fine. What could have caused this?

I remember updated Django 1.1.1 from 1.1, don't remember the performance after this.

Any clues or ideas to try to improve performance?

Thanks.

Edit: I am running Mac OS on a MacPro

Comment: it may not be easy to find, but this sounds very much like a DNS issue.  Maybe ask on serverfault/superuser for more information about tracking it down.

Comment: Shouldn't be a DNS issue as `localhost` gets not resolved via DNS ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you modify your /etc/hosts file at all?  What about if you try http://127.0.0.1:8000 is it still slow?

Comment: Yes I changed the /etc/hosts to update mysql server info. And accessing with http://127.0.0.1:8000 is also slow.

Comment: My database server was running in a Parallels VM and during the reconfig of router somehow the IP range was very slow. The modem had 192.168.1.x and the wireless router had (10.0.0.x). I changed the wireless router to 192.168.2.x as well as the interface to "Host-only" from "Bridged Networking". Now the performance is what I expect in 'localhost'